# jquery datepicker is not working after navigation to another component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i'm using the following versions,
jquery: ^3.3.1
jquery-ui: 1.12.1
angularjs 6
So here's my code,
.html has this definition

```
<input id="test" type="text" class="form-control"  value="">
```

and in my component (component.ts file)

```
ngOnInit() {
 $('#test').datepicker({
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true,
       yearRange: "1930:2010"});

}
```

On loading the page for the first time datepicker pops up but, after navigation and coming back to this page it doesnt popup again.

after inspecting the elements in browser i found that, this dynamic `<div>` is not getting created.

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 732.078px; z-index: 1; display: block;">
```

where am i going wrong, can anyone please help?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Can you post a fiddle with your code

Comment: Its pretty complicated angularjs structure i have, really difficult to create a fiddle. But can you please tell me if jquery and jquery-ui version matters for datepicker?

Answer (score 2):

As i am not able to write comment i am writing this answer.
So ngOnInit runs only once on app initialization.So that is the why your datepicker is not getting rendered when navigating back to the view.
According to angular official documentation

> **ngOnInit()**
>
> A callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change
> detector has checked the directive's data-bound properties for the
> first time, and before any of the view or content children have been
> checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

May be you can make use ngAfterViewInit() hook or any appropriate hook from lifecycle. Now dont throw tomatoes at me as i am not actively using angular,but i thought  i can help.

Comment: I tried ngAfterViewInit(), still its not working the second time. Do i have to destroy the element or something?

Comment: As i mentioned you have to check for appropriate lifecycle hook that runs each time the view gets rendered. Hope it helps